# Get the xml value in reverse order

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml getting from SqlTable like this.

```
<root>
 <item> 
   <Column1>
    <TT TXT1="Item3" />
    <TT TXT1="Item2" />
    <TT TXT1="Item1" /> 
   </Column1>
 </item>
</root>
```

I need to print this values in the web page in descending order .means Print like

```
Item1  Item2   Item3
```

like this

I tried some code like

```
<xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="$Item.xml//TT/@TXT1"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="$txt1-atts">
<xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it didn't get the values.anybody help...??

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<xsl:for-each select="$txt1-atts">
  <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to process the attributes in reverse order.

Comment: I don't see any `<xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>` in the sample you posted.

Comment: Okey...  I Tried this one but the  txt1-atts  didn't have any value.why this??

Comment: In your sample `<xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="$Item.xml//TT/@TXT1"></xsl:variable>` looks wrong as well, you might want `<xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="document('Item.xml')//TT/@TXT1"/>`. That assumes the file `Item.xml` is a secondary input document to your transformation. I am not sure that is the case, if you still have problems then edit your question to provide minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem (where does `$Item` come from)?

Comment: the item comming from the stored procedure


<xsl:variable name="Item" select="shop:ExecStoredProcedure('kt_Item',concat('@Dcat:',$p//defaultcategory))"></xsl:variable>


and so I used   <xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="$Item.xml//TT/@TXT1"></xsl:variable>

Comment: If the variable name is `Item` then the variable reference in your XPath should be `$Item` and not `$Item.xml`. But I don't know how stored procedures and their return types interact with XSLT/XPath so I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe someone else can help if you tag the question with the corresponding tag of the framework or API you use.